# How visible is a SharePoint Site Collection to users without access?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

I've received a request to create a new "secret" site in our SP Farm which will have a very restricted set of users, and should be entirely invisible to other users of our SP site. Ideally, nobody* should have any idea that the site exists.

I'm planning on creating this as a Site Collection, partially so that it won't exist as a sub-site in any other site's All Site Content. Also, I intend to exclude this SC from search indexing, and of course it's permissions will be restricted.

Is there any other way a normal (non admin) user could see that a Site Collection exists if they don't have permission to it?

Comment: Why exclude it from indexing? Search results are security-trimmed, so a user with no access should see no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is if the user guessed the URL.  Then they would see the "Not Authorized" page and know something was there.